# Binomial distribution with a binomial parameter

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a binomial distribution with parameters $(M,p)$ and $Y|X$ be a binomial distribution with parameters $(X,q)$, then $Y$ is a binomial distribution with parameters $(M, pq)$.

I've so far tried $P(Y=j) = \sum_{X=k}^{X=M}P(Y=j | X = k)P(X = k) = \sum_{k=0}^M \binom{k}{j}q^j(1-q)^{k-j} \binom{M}{k}p^k(1-p)^{M-k}$, but I can't figure out how to show that this ultimately equals $\binom{M}{j}(pq)^j(1-pq)^{M-j}$.

I've tried looking at the MGF of $X$ as $(1-p+pe^s)^M$, but with no luck.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Going a bit brute force here for exposition.

If $X=0$, $Y=0$ w.p. 1

If $X=1$, $Y=0$ w.p. $1-q$ and $Y=1$ w.p. $q$

If $X=2$, $Y=0$ w.p. $(1-q)^2$, $Y=1$ w.p.$2q(1-q)$, and $Y=2$ w.p. $q^2$.

$\ldots$

If $X=M$, $Y=0$ w.p. $(1-q)^M$, $Y=1$ w.p.p $Mq(1-q)^{M-1}$, etc.

Thus,
$P(Y=0) = 1 \times P(X=0) + (1-q) \times P(X=1) + \ldots + (1-q)^M P(X=M)$

$=(1-p)^M + (1-q) Mp(1-p)^{M-1} + \ldots + (1-q)^M p^M$

$= (1-p + p(1-q))^M$ (binomial expansion)

$= (1-pq)^M$ (consistent with a binomial $(M, pq)$ distribution

This is of course not a complete proof, but if you try it out for $P(Y=1)$, $P(Y=2)$ etc. I think it will lead you to a general form for $P(Y=k)$.